# Variable declared inside !IsPostBack is getting null on button click -c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

How can I get the values declared on variables through out the page? Now in my code, button click (btn_details_Click) gets student_id and dept_id as null.

```
    public partial class TaskDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private  int student_id;
        private  int dept_id;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
             student_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["selected_student_id"]);
             dept_id=GetDeptID(student_id );
            }
        }
        protected void btn_details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["selected_studentID"] = student_id;
            Session["selected_DEPT_ID"] = dept_id;

            Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Every time there's a postback, such as by clicking a button, a *new* instance of the `TaskDetails` class will be constructed and so if you don't set member variables to any value they'll remain unset. The code you're showing doesn't make a whole heap of sense anyway (when you press the button, the value we originally got from the session is set back in the session, which it'll still be set to anyway?)

Comment: Also, in 2022 I wouldn't be recommending people spend time building new code using the ASP.Net Web Forms model, personally.

Comment: You use 2 different names for the session... `selected_student_id` and `selected_studentID`